# Как правильно выстроить работу приложения и сервера для проверки лицензии?

Tags: шифрование, кэширование

Я прочитал про DSS и DSA, но до конца не понимаю как выстроена работа. Правильно ли я понимаю, что: получается пара из публичного и приватного ключа, мы даем пользователю публичный ключ и при первом запуске на сервер отправляется уникальная информация о ПК в виде хэша, этот хэш привязывается к приватному ключу. При следующих запусках отправляется хэш и публичный ключ, на сервере лицензий, из приватного ключа(который определяется благодаря отправленному публичному ключу) и хэша, получается цифровая подпись, эта цифровая подпись отправляется в приложение, тут на основе публичного ключа строится функция "проверятель", которая сравнивает цифровую подпись и хэш текущего пк.